# Are there black holes without accretion disk but emitting astrophysical jets?

Tags: black-holes, accretion-disk, relativistic-jets

First a citation from Wikipedia page about relativistic jets:
"Jets may also be observed from spinning neutron stars. An example is pulsar IGR J11014-6103, which has the largest jet so far observed in the Milky Way Galaxy, and whose velocity is estimated at 80% the speed of light (0.8c). X-ray observations have been obtained but there is no detected radio signature nor accretion disk.[18][19] Initially, this pulsar was presumed to be rapidly spinning but later measurements indicate the spin rate is only 15.9 Hz.[20][21]"

Now, if the pulsar has no accretion disk and emits the astroph. jet can somebody ask himself could exist black holes with no accretion disk that also emit that kind of jets but in that case the complication is that these jets should derive somehow from the interior of the event horizon which is not plausible and so making impossible the existence of that kind of black holes?